# Superset load_examles failed

Tags: apache-superset

I execute the following command as part of the superset installation process:

```
superset load_examples
```

But it results to error as follows:

Loading examples metadata and related data into examples

Creating default CSS templates

Loading energy related dataset

Traceback (most recent call last):

...

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

...

urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it seems like the computer running Superset can't access the broader internet. I believe downloading the datasets to load the example dashboards needs internet access.

Answer (score 0):

Since the path of superset examples is in github's apache-superset ,it is easy to fail to download due to network problems.The best way is to download examples  zip directly from github, modify the read path of superset examples, and then load examples directly from the local path,it works.

Please entre link and follow the video
[youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xPnCFwJtDw)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).